# Which of the following are metric on C

Tags: metric-spaces

If $C=\{f \mid f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R\}$, then which of the following are metrics on $C$?

1. $d(f,g)=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}$,
2. $d(f,g)=\inf\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}$,
3. $d(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|\,dx$,
4. $d(f,g)=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}+\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|\,dx$.

Comment: Please post your work on this question also in here.

Comment: Once you have your work posted, we may be able to help you out.

Comment: Excuse me, @BrianM.Scott  , he has to post his work too in here !

Comment: @Spectre: He’d certainly get a better response if he did. However, that’s a separate issue from simply getting the question posted so that it’s readable, something that I don’t mind doing for someone who may not yet have learned to use MathJax.

Comment: There is a MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ok........ thanks, @BrianM.Scott ..

Comment: But if distance is infinity then what is problem please anyone reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, none of these are metrics.

1. Not a metric because the $\sup$ could be infinity; distances must be real-valued
2. Not a metric because $d(f, g) = 0$ where $g(x) = x$ and $f(x) = x^2$ - a distance of zero should mean that $f = g$
3. Not a metric because $|f - g|$ may not be integrable
4. Not a metric for the same reasons as both 1 and 3

If you redefine $C = \{f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R} : f$ continuous$\}$, then 1, 2, and 4 are all metrics.

Comment: You mean 1, 3 and 4?